# SharedPreferences gets reset when Android app is in SD Card

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have an Android app with login functionality. The login credentials are saved in SharedPreferences. Now when I move app my in SD Card, app gets logged out on device restart. That means SharedPreferences are getting reset on app restart when app is present in SD Card. Is there a way to prevent this behaviour?